# Can BIOS be modified to fake hardware information?

Tags: laptop, bios, hardware-detection

I had my laptop repaired for a power circuit issue recently. During the repair the technician stole some of the RAM, claiming one of the chips was broken and so he removed it, but he removed both chips and installed a single different chip.

However, I'm concerned he may have stolen some other components of the computer as well, such as CPU or GPU. If so, he would have had to modify the BIOS to fake the hardware information because I know what hardware my BIOS reported previously, and it is reporting the same now, but I'm still concerned.

So, is it possible to modify the BIOS so that it reports different hardware than is actually installed?

I know he did not modify the software because I removed the hard drive from the computer before giving it to the technician for repair.

Comment: My laptop has 2 RAMs of 4GB (so total of 8GB), but now I lost 1 and it reports only 4 GB of course.

Comment: No he's not of that kind, please see my comment above. I have 2 RAMs of 4 GBs, he reported that 1 was failed and gave back to me the failed one. But that failed one is a totally different RAM compared to the original one I had (I have proof of that).

Comment: @Ramhound sorry about that, I wanted to type 4 but the number 1 (1 RAM) was in my head

Comment: How do you know both sticks were the same before? What is different about them now?

Comment: @HazardousGlitch I have a snapshot of them I took before, isn't that enough? And of course this time is the first time my laptop repaired. I once myself have tried opening it up to sanitize my laptop before (about 6 months ago). Even now I can check my remaining RAM, it is the original one (manufactured by Huyndai Electronics - made in Korea). The failed one I received from him has brand of Nanya (made in Taiwan). That's a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the technician did not modify your BIOS to report different hardware.  While this is *technically* possible, if the technician had the ability to do this, he certainly would not be working as a computer repair tech.

Almost all laptops have the CPUs soldered onto their motherboards.  The process of removing them and soldering a new one in place requires very expensive, specialized equipment.  This is not a piece of equipment you find at a standard computer shop.

Even if your CPU was one of the *very* few that are socketed and removable from the motherboard, what good would it do him?  The odds of him having a laptop motherboard that is compatible with it is slim to none.  Additionally, why would he have another CPU to put it its place?

All of the above applies to the GPU, as well.  It is very rare to find a laptop with a removable GPU.

As for the memory, if you had a power issue, it is not uncommon for a memory module to be damaged.  Perhaps both modules were non-functional and he simply put a spare module in, so the computer would work.  I cannot speak to why he gave you back the wrong memory.  Perhaps it was an honest mistake.  The only way to get an answer to that is to ask him.  Additionally, there is no real financial gain.  RAM is cheap.  Depending on the type and speed, a used 4GB RAM module can go for as little as $15.

In summary, you are simply being overly paranoid.  I think you should simply talk to the tech about him giving you back the wrong RAM.  He *should* have given you back the defective RAM, so you could verify it for yourself.